# AdMob Interstitial Ads Loading Repeatedly onResume

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I want to load AdMob interstitial ads when the users opens the app and resumes the app after minimizing the app.

I am using the following code to load AdMob interstitial ads `onResume`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad));
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request);

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        showInterstitial();
    }
});
}
```

But the ads keep loading repeatedly after closing. I tried to limit ads display once in 5 minutes in AdMob settings but it didn't work. How do I prevent ads from loading repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to load AdMob interstitial ads when the users opens the app and
>   resumes the app after minimizing the app.

This is prohibited as per interstitial best practices: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287.

Your code creates a circuit. You are loading the interstitial on the activity's `onResume()`, and showing it when `onAdLoaded()` is fired. However, for `onAdLoaded()` is fired, the interstitial must have been visibly displayed from before. So, since the interstitial is still around, it will dispatch `onAdLoaded()`, which shows the interstitial (`showInterstitial()`), which will dispatch another `onAdLoaded()`, which will call `showInterstitial()` again and again.

You need to send the ad request early, and utilize the [`isLoaded()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd.html#isLoaded()) check before calling `showInterstitial()`.

Send the ad request on app launch:

```
// Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

// Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

// Defined in res/values/strings.xml
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));

if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Then, put this in your `showInterstitial()`:

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

**EDIT**: Only call `showInterstitial()` at a logical breakpoint in your app. Showing interstitial ads on app launches or app exits does not comply with AdMob's interstitial best practices.